# Zohar's interpretation of Bereshit 1

Tags: commentaries, mysticism-kabbalah, parashat-bereishit, zohar

The Zohar's interpretation of the words 'Bereshit bara Elohim', usually translated as 'In the beginning G-d created', seems not to understand the word Elohim to be the subject of the verb bara, but instead as the object of the verb. The act of 'bara' is done 'with Reshit'.

Hopefully I got it right, but the Zohar seems to understand that when HaShem sought to be revealed, He produced at first a single point which ascended to become thought, it was the beginning of creation, a process in which a spark sprang forth from the Ein Sof; this point of light is what the Zohar calls ‘Reshit’. From this beginning point things began to unfold through the different sefirot, or emanations of divine light. The Zohar adds that the word Elohim is composed of the two words: mi (who), and eleh (these).

Looking back at the words 'Bereshit bara Elohim' what does the Zohar tries to teach us interpreting these words to mean that 'with the Reshit', with this starting point this spark, He created Elohim. What does this mean? Does this mean HaShem created the concept of Elohim?

Afterwards we do read it's with the title of Elohim and with speech, that things begin to unfold.

Could someone please explain the basis that the Zohar presents to us here for understanding the first chapter of Bereshit?

Comment: Without getting into a very wide ranging discussion, it sounds like you are trying to understand the concept of the creation of ‘names’. G-d at His essence transcends even the aspect of letters & names. So for example, the מי ברא אלה of אלהים alludes to, among other things, the union of יהוה & אהיה. Which when including words & kollel totals 50, the value of the מ״י portion of אלהים. And this evolves from בראשית, meaning ברא שית, the union of the feminine name with the masculine name to be one in the 6 letter name אהיהוה.

Comment: Most of your second paragraph seems reminiscent of the Hindu Vedas. As for its last sentence, rulers (since this is the basic meaning of the word *elohim*) require subjects to rule over, hence *who* (singular, the ruler) and *these* (plural, those being ruled).